# question incorrectly marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558318/rand-function-in-c-generate-even-and-odd-number-with-a-periodic-of-3276800) was actually asking why correctly generated random numbers exhibited repeated sequences of values in the low bits.  It was tagged as a duplicate of another question asking [why the author kept getting the same number every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926622/how-to-generate-different-random-number-in-a-loop-in-c?lq=1) (answer: s/he was incorrectly reinitializing the generator between calls).  The two cases are quite distinct and have completely different explanations for the observed behavior.

I'm not an author/responder for either question, but I'd like to see the moderation corrected because the first question identifies an important issue in random number generation that is completely unrelated to the second question.

Comment: `status-completed`; the question has now been reopened.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the inappropriate cross-link to the other question?

Comment: The link in the right-hand 'linked' list? I *think* that that is cached and will be updated soon enough. Do you care that much?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Since the question in the right-hand 'linked' list is actually unrelated I don't see any point in maintaining the link, but it's not a big deal.  More curious than anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree. The questions are different. I voted to reopen. For the record, it was not closed by a moderator, but by 5 3K+ users.